# How to configure Virtualbox to assign a separate mac address to the vm?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have  Kali linux running on Virtualbox and I have used bridged network mode to assign separate IP to the virtual machine. 
The problem I'm facing is that on my server when I arping the vm, I see my computer's MAC address instead of the MAC address of the vm assigned by Kali.

Is there a way to get around this ? I want the server to see all the requests coming from the vm, having its own MAC, not my PC's MAC.

Comment: Is your host connected via wifi or via ethernet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bridged networking in your VM, and then you got another MAC address, or you can easily generate a different one.